# Word/Phrase to describe an ungrateful person that becomes aware of their own selfishness/arrogance

Tags: phrases

Looking for a phrase to describe someone that becomes aware of their own selfishness or arrogance, and is then deeply remorseful. And then feels that they have a great "debt" to repay back to the people they hurt, or took advantage of.

Comment: I'm thinking there is likely a good literary reference for this -- a fictional character who went through this transformation -- but I can't think of one at present.

Comment: Ah, yes!!  Ebenezer Scrooge!

Comment: @HotLicks I like the literacy reference. It paints a good picture.

Comment: There are probably a few others, in works that are less well known.  Maybe someone else will come up with a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**penitent**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/penitent) Can be used as a adj. or noun

> feeling or expressing sorrow for sin or wrongdoing and disposed to
> atonement (amends /or reparations)

Comment: Thank you, I love this word. This is exactly what I needed.